# How to check the touch points of the circles as in the image in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, geometry

I am facing problem in getting the touch point of the circle for the game i was developing 
[image: circle inside circle]

I tried to solve this by getting the points as below

```
public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable){   
if(!this.isVisible() || this.getTouchable() == Touchable.disabled)
      return null;

    // Get center-point of bounding circle, also known as the center of the Rect

float centerX = _texture.getRegionWidth() / 2;
    float centerY = _texture.getRegionHeight() / 2;

    // Calculate radius of circle

float radius = (float) (Math.sqrt(centerX * centerX + centerY * centerY))-5f;

// And distance of point from the center of the circle
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(((centerX - x) * (centerX - x)) 
               + ((centerY - y) * (centerY - y)));

    // If the distance is less than the circle radius, it's a hit
    if(distance <= radius) return this;

    // Otherwise, it isn't
    return null;}
```

I am getting hit positions inside circle but also the points around it near black spots, i only need the touch points near circle.
Would some body suggest the approach for achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a Circle object in your Actor: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Circle.html
Then check if the circle contains that point using the circle.contains(float x, float y) function.
Basically it'll look something like this:

```
public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable){   
      if(!this.isVisible() || this.getTouchable() == Touchable.disabled) 
            return null;

      if (circle.contains(x,y)) return this;

       return null;
}
```

Of course the downside is that if this is a dynamic object and it moves around a lot, then you'd have to constantly update the circles position. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have 10 to 15 circles like that in my game, how to add circle object to my actor .If i had to add even 1 how could i do that?

Comment: How can i differentiate the 3 inner layers with respect to the radius?

Comment: To add a circle object to your actor, you'll have to create a new class that extends from whatever original Actor class (or create a class that extends directly from Actor if you want to go that low). As for differentiating the 3 inner layers, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that every circle layer is a new actor? Are you making some sort of a darts game and you need to detect where the dart hits? If that's the case make one class, say dartCircleLayer, then create 3 objects with the right sizes and place them on top of each other correctly.

Comment: Continue of last comment: Then add them to stage in the right order and the stage should be checking from smallest inner circle to largest outer circle.

Answer (score 3):

Im guessing that you are comparing local rect coordinates (ie centerX, centerY) with screen coordinates x,y parameters that you are feeding to the function.

So you probably want to subtract the rect's x,y position from the parameters x,y so your parameters are in local coordinates.

So:
float lLocalX = x-rectX (assuming this is the rects x position on the screen)
float lLocalY = y-rectY (assuming this is the rects y position on the screen)

now you can compare them!

float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(((centerX - lLocalX ) * (centerX - lLocalX )) 
               + ((centerY - lLocalY ) * (centerY - lLocalY )));

Comment: Would you be more specific about the local co-ordinates.

Comment: centerX,centerY are relative to your rectange x,y. So if the rectangle is at 100,100 then CenterX are really on the screen at 100+CenterX, 100+CenterY. When you call hit function with screen coordinates it wont compare correctly unless you 1. adjust the parameters (by deducating the rectangle x,y), OR 2. adjust CenterX, CenterY (by adding the rectangle x,y).